# GetMethod to get Dispose(bool disposing) dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, getmethod, typebuilder

I am currently trying to implement a class that uses *TypeBuilder* to dynamically create a new class that derives from a class that itself derives from *DbContext* (i.o.w. the dynamic class indirectly inherits from *DbContext*).

To override (with *DefineMethod* + *DefineMethodOverride*) the *Dispose* class I need to retrieve it first using *GetMethod*. I was able to retrieve the `SaveChanges()` method by using the following:

```
typeof(TBaseDbContext).GetMethod("SaveChanges")
```

However the *Dispose(bool disposing)* is quite different in that it is protected and has arguments.

Narrowing down on the problem I came to the following code:

```
        MethodInfo disposeOfBase =
            typeof(DbContext).GetMethod("Dispose",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null,
                CallingConventions.Any,
                new Type[] { typeof(bool) },
                null);
```

The result in *disposeOfBase* is null. I have tried different combinations but I think the above should be near to correct. I have no idea why the *Dispose* is not found.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I modify the code so that disposeOfBase holds the info of the protected *Dispose* method of *DbContext*?

Comment: Try `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`. You must specify either Instance or Static to get a method back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and it worked, so I'm posting the above comment as an answer:

Try `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`. [You must specify either Instance or Static to get a method back](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s2kzbw8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, that indeed was the problem. Thanks!